# A relation of the prime counting function $\pi$ to counting the ordered ways of a number $n$ as a sum of two primes and two questions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, goldbach-type-problems

The definitions are from these two questions:

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164216/a-series-related-to-prime-numbers
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349186/trying-to-understand-apply-the-hilbert-serre-theorem-in-a-specific-situation

Let $H(t)$ be the Hilbert–Poincaré series of $V := \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} V_n $, where $V_n := \left\langle \log(1), \cdots, \log(n) \right\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}}$ where it is used that:

1. $\log(n) = \sum_{p\mid n} v_p(n) \log(p)$
2. $\log(p)$ with $p$ prime, are linearly independent over the rational numbers.

Then $\pi(n) = \dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(V_n)$.

So we have $H(t) = \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \pi(n)t^n$ where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.  By the prime number theorem, the radius of convergence is $1$. Observing $\pi(n) = \pi(n-1)+1$ if $n$ is prime and $\pi(n) = \pi(n-1)$ if $n$ is composite, we might rewrite this as $H(t) = f(t)/(1-t)$ where $f(t) =\sum_{p \text{ prime }} t^p$. Define the sequence $b_n$ for $n=-1,0,1,2,\cdots$ as $ f'(t)/f(t) = \sum_{n=-1} b_n t^n$. Then we can recover the primes from this sequence:

$$ p = 2 + \sum_{q <p, q \text{ prime }} b_{p-1-q}$$

For example:

For example the first coefficients are given by the series:

$$2*t^{(-1)} + 1 + (-1)*t + 4*t^2 + (-5)*t^3 + 11*t^4 + (-16)*t^5 + 22*t^6 + (-37)*t^7 + 67*t^8 + (-101)*t^9 + 166*t^{10} + (-260)*t^{11} + 404*t^{12} + (-652)*t^{13} + \cdots $$

so $b_{-1} = 2, b_0 = 1, b_1 = -1 , b_2 = 4$ etc.

We have for example:

$$3 = 2+b_0 = 2+1$$

$$5 = 2+b_2+b_1 = 2+4-1$$

$$7 = 2+b_4+b_3+b_1 = 2+11-5-1$$
Let $a_{n,k}$ denote the number of ordered ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $k$ primes.
Then after some calculation, one finds that:
$$a_{n,k} = \frac{k}{n-2k} \sum_{v=0}^{n-1} {a_{v,k} b_{n-1-v}}$$
which is a recurence relation.
Furthermore if $\alpha_n$ $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$ are all roots of $f(t)$ not equal to zero, then for $n\ge 0$
$$ b_n = - \sum_{k=0} ^ \infty \frac{1}{\alpha_k^{n+1}}$$

The numbers $b_n$ might be computed inductively using:
$$ n a_{n,1} = \sum_{v=0}^n b_{v-1} a_{n-v,1}$$
from which one sees, that $b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

One real root of $f(t)$ seems to be the number,

$$ \gamma = -0.62923 \cdots $$

(OEIS: http://oeis.org/A078756 )

For $\gamma$ numerical coincidences suggest that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = \gamma = -0.629233\cdots$$

which could be one way to define $\gamma$. Then one has to show, that this limit exists and that $f(\gamma) = 0$.

**Q1)** If someone has an idea in this direction,that would be nice.

Using $H(t)^2 = f(t)^2/(1-t)^2$ and the Cauchy-formula for multiplication of power series and comparing coefficients of $t$, one finds that:

$$\pi^*(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n \pi(k) \pi(n-k) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k,2}(n-k+1)$$

Solving this last formula for $a_{n,2}$ and using induction on $n$ we find that:

$$a_{n,2} = \pi^*(n)-2 \pi^*(n-1)+\pi^*(n-2)$$

which reflects the title chosen. Using this, the Goldbach conjecture might be written as:

$$\forall n \ge 2: \frac{\pi^*(2n)+\pi^*(2n-2)}{2} > \pi^*(2n-1)$$

A quick test shows, that this inequality is very difficult to achieve...:

```
n lhs rhs lhs>rhs
0 0.0 0 False
1 0.0 0 False
2 0.5 0 True
3 4.5 4 True
4 15.0 14 True
5 33.5 32 True
6 59.0 58 True
7 91.5 90 True
8 134.0 132 True
9 186.0 184 True
10 248.0 246 True
11 322.5 320 True
12 409.0 406 True
13 508.5 506 True
14 620.0 618 True
15 741.0 738 True
16 874.0 872 True
17 1021.5 1018 True
18 1184.0 1180 True
19 1359.5 1358 True
20 1547.0 1544 True
21 1748.0 1744 True
22 1965.0 1962 True
23 2199.5 2196 True
24 2451.0 2446 True
25 2722.0 2718 True
26 3011.0 3008 True
27 3315.0 3310 True
28 3637.0 3634 True
29 3975.5 3972 True
30 4330.0 4324 True
31 4704.5 4702 True
32 5099.0 5094 True
33 5514.0 5508 True
34 5948.0 5946 True
35 6399.0 6394 True
36 6870.0 6864 True
37 7364.5 7360 True
38 7883.0 7878 True
39 8425.0 8418 True
```

On the other hand we know that

$$\pi^*(n)-2 \pi^*(n-1)+\pi^*(n-2) = a_{n,2} = \frac{2}{n-4} \sum_{v=0}^{n-1} {a_{v,2} b_{n-1-v}}$$

Hence there is a relation between $\pi^*$ and the numbers $b_l$.
Nowing this relation we might insert for $b_l$ the $\pi^*$ and hence get a "formula" for the $n$-th prime in terms of evaluation of $\pi^*$, since

$$ p = 2+ \sum_{q<p} b_{p-1-q}$$

**Q2)** Is it possible to find such a relation?

**Attachment**:
Here is the computation for the recurence relation of $a_{n,k}$:
For $k\ge 1$ we have on the one hand:
$$\log(f(t)^k)' = \frac{k f(t)^{k-1} f'(t)}{f(t)^k} = k \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} = \sum_{n=-1}^\infty k b_n t^n$$

On the other hand it is
$$f(t)^k  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,k}t^n$$
which means that
$$\log(f(t)^k)' = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_{n,k} t^{n-1}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty  a_{n,k} t^{n}}$$

Hence it follows, that (by multiplying with the denominator):
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_{n,k} t^{n-1} = k (\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,k} t^{n}) (\sum_{n=0} b_{n-1}t^n) \frac{1}{t}$$

After multiplying with $t$ and using the Cauchy product formula we get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n a_{n,k} t^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty k( \sum_{v=0}^n a_{v,k}b_{n-1-v})t^n$$

and comparing coefficients we find that:

$$n a_{n,k} = k ( \sum_{v=0}^n a_{v,k} b_{n-1-v})$$

and with $b_{-1} = 2$ it follows after solving this equation for $a_{n,k}$ that:

$$ a_{n,k} = \frac{k}{n-2k} \sum_{v=0}^{n-1} a_{v,k} b_{n-1-v}$$

Especially for $k=1$ and $n=p$ prime we find that:

$$ p = 2+ \sum_{q<p} b_{p-1-q}$$

**Edit**:
It seems that the $\pi^*$ functions satisfies the following inequality:
Suppose $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are natural numbers such that the arithemetic mean of these numbers is also a natural number, then my conjecture is :

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \pi^*(x_i) \ge \pi^*(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i)$$

**Q3)** If a proof of this inequality can be done, then it would be nice to share it.

Thanks for your help!

Notice that for $x_1 = 2n, x_2 = 2n-2$ and $\ge$ replaced with $>$ we have the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: also asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350183/goldbach-and-the-prime-counting-function in case it is not research related.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Post to **one** site. If, after the passage of several days, the question is not resolved to your satisfaction, *then* post to another site (with links both ways, and explanation).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry that I am not aware if the question is research related or not. I will delete the question here on this forum and will wait as you suggest a few days.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I deleted the MSE question, and put the question back here, because at MSE it was suggested to close the question, because of "lack of focus", whatever that means.

Comment: I think your last equality boils down to saying $\pi^{*}$ is convex. If convexity is preserved under multiplication of power series, it may suffice to prove $\pi$ is itself convex

Comment: It seems I mixed up concavity and convexity. The overall idea remains the same though.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Nice observation. Did you do any computer based calculation to back up your observation a little bit?

Comment: I did no calculation whatsoever, I just visualised the graph of $\pi(x)$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I tested both of your conjecture, but they seem to not hold.