# Why does this convolution of the prime counting function $\pi$ look like a parabola?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, convolution, goldbach-type-problems

In [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413272/a-relation-of-the-prime-counting-function-pi-to-counting-the-ordered-ways-of) it is shown that the convolution of the prime counting function $\pi$ with itself, is related to the Goldbach conjecture:

$$\pi^*(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n \pi(k) \pi(n-k)$$

The Goldbach conjecture might be written as:

$$\forall n \ge 2: \frac{\pi^*(2n)+\pi^*(2n-2)}{2} > \pi^*(2n-1)$$

I have plotted the function $\pi^*$ and it looks like a parabola:

[image: Goldbach_conjecture_prime_counting_function_convolution]

**Question: Is there any explanation for this observation or is this superficial observation maybe wrong?**

[Here is some SageMath Code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytUkFuwyAQvEfKH5BPYFMrTnuqlFvVP1RWFBGMU2QDK8CpndcXHJJUTdtTbUu7XmZnZoFGtAhAYk2elwsUHiv8YDVyg8I1WKnELqx2JL_m-qEjqDUWdUhqZJk-CKyLimzJchHf5t8ZpQJjPQKmG-ZQ-KCZhZhnaBN-ypeQvVqmBOamH5R2oVxnY0azKdvSiNvUuKMw695JVatVkmqtUchxCVNpwEslTwIlcT7Yo9i10l9GbAfN8UgZ3VNOGyq-TcvyMc-fin0MjwWPYV00IYhIAIGeIuDmGJxeqXHkpCj6LccUp9nYVSXAcWyeq1YcrHBOGr0DI7WPY_fSeXySgBPLbDPlN68k9LO-_73trP1Hd5ihipvfG4_PLPjOTsTBOqKq4ivwZzFy4Z2Ra1K6d_OB0xUId0V7nI10om9ZqMUjhHiEtynS_p-RQD4BPELgBQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to compute parameters $a,b,c,d,e$ for regression:

$$an^4+bn^3+cn^2+dn+e \approx \pi^*(n)$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Given the prime number theorem asymptotic, it looks heuristically like one could expect this function to grow polynomially (sort of). Ignoring the logarithm in the denominator of the asymptotic, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k(n-k) \approx \frac{n^3}{2} - \frac{n^3}{3}$. I know little about analytic number theory so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: It seems your reformulation of Goldbach's conjecture boils down to showing the function $\pi^{*}$ is convex, which may be achieved through mathematicals means outside mere analytical number theory.

Comment: Ok, I just found out I made a similar comment to your previous question. Have you tried replacing $\pi$ by its expression worked out by Riemann in his famous memoir? The conjectured convexity may be tightly related to RH and maybe to the vertical distribution of critical zeros of Zeta as well.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN no, not yet. have started it but not gone through the computation.

Comment: Do you mean the Goldbach conjecture that every even counting number greater than 2 is equal to the sum of two prime numbers? If not, could you please give a reference to the conjecture you're referring to as the Goldbach conjecture?

Comment: @StevenClark yes, that is what I mean. The reference is thd first linked question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is straightforward to show that
$$\pi^*(n)\sim\frac{n^3}{6\log^2 n}.\tag{$\ast$}\label{ast}$$
So the graph of $\pi^*(n)$ does not look like a parabola. Instead, it looks like the graph of $\frac{n^3}{\log^2 n}$.

Indeed, we have
$$\sum_{\min(k,n-k)<\frac{n}{\log n}} \pi(k) \pi(n-k)\ll\frac{n}{\log n}\pi(n)^2\ll\frac{n^3}{\log^3 n},$$
and also
\begin{align*}\sum_{\min(k,n-k)\geq\frac{n}{\log n}} \pi(k) \pi(n-k)&\sim\frac{1}{\log n^2}\sum_{\min(k,n-k)\geq\frac{n}{\log n}}k(n-k)\\&\sim\frac{1}{\log n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n k(n-k)\\&\sim\frac{n^3}{6\log^2 n}.\end{align*}
Here we used that for $\min(k,n-k)\geq\frac{n}{\log n}$, both $\log k$ and $\log(n-k)$ are asymptotically $\log n$.

**Added.** The asymptotic formula \eqref{ast} converges rather slowly. Here are some numeric data:
\begin{align*}
\pi^*(10^2)&=16329\\
\pi^*(10^3)&=6311273\\
\pi^*(10^4)&=3119183737\\
\pi^*(10^5)&=1817310193749\\
\pi^*(10^6)&=1181102034701650\\
\pi^*(10^7)&=827525141442938787\\
\pi^*(10^8)&=611768346585852887680
\end{align*}
The corresponding ratios of the two sides of \eqref{ast} are:
\begin{align*}
n=10^2\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 2.0778\\
n=10^3\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.8069\\
n=10^4\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.5876\\
n=10^5\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.4453\\
n=10^6\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.3526\\
n=10^7\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.2899\\
n=10^8\quad \rightsquigarrow\quad 1.2455
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, for this proof. :-) How difficult is it to prove asymptotically the Goldbach conjecture? :-) If it is possible at all, I do not know. (Sorry for my naive question concerning Goldbach.)

Comment: @mathoverflowUser We don't know if the Goldbach conjecture is true. If it is false, then it is impossible to prove it. If it is true, then it is probably very hard to prove it as it has been an open problem for 280 years.

Comment: Yes ok, I understand. I just checked that your approximate formula for $\pi^*$ satisfies the inequality of Goldbach given above ( up to n=3000).... So this is funny. :-) I have updated the quesiton with your formula.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser Yes, but the asymptotic formula is useless for the inequality.

Comment: Right, I was too entusiasthic. :-) Sorry for that!

Comment: @mathoverflowUser See my Added section for some numeric aspects.

Comment: I understand that asymptotics are not good for inequalities, in this case.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser My Added section is for fun. I just updated it.